# parsing DataTable XML output, junk after document element error

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable

I'm trying to get database records and print them in XML markup.

With `DataTable` class, the output is like this:

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns=""
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="c" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="c">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <DocumentElement
        xmlns="">
        <c diffgr:id="c1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <ID>12224</ID>
            <TYPE>2</TYPE>
        </c>
        <c diffgr:id="c2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
            <ID>12225</ID>
            <TYPE>2</TYPE>
        </c>
        <c diffgr:id="c3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
            <ID>12298</ID>
            <TYPE>1</TYPE>
        </c>
        <c diffgr:id="c4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
            <ID>12299</ID>
            <TYPE>1</TYPE>
        </c>
        <c diffgr:id="c5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
            <ID>12300</ID>
            <TYPE>1</TYPE>
        </c>
        <c diffgr:id="c6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
            <ID>12301</ID>
            <TYPE>1</TYPE>
        </c>
    </DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

It seems valid, but when I tried to parse it in another PHP script, it throws an error:

`XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Line Number 20, Column 1`

What's the problem? Live demo at codebeutify: http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/848b20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each XML file might contain only a single root element. Yours has two: `xs:schema` and `diffgr:diffgram`. You should put the schema to a separate xsd file and reference it where required.